# Customize Ribbon Health Check URL

Tags: java, spring-cloud

I wonder how I can customize the health check URL for Ribbon.  For the example [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/client-side-load-balancing/), there is:

```
public class SayHelloConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  IClientConfig ribbonClientConfig;

  @Bean
  public IPing ribbonPing(IClientConfig config) {
    return new PingUrl();
  }

  @Bean
  public IRule ribbonRule(IClientConfig config) {
    return new AvailabilityFilteringRule();
  }

}
```

And `PingUrl ()` check will just ping the "/" path.  I didn't find anywhere that I can customize this path.

Answer (score 1):

What about using this constructor? https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/blob/master/ribbon-httpclient/src/main/java/com/netflix/loadbalancer/PingUrl.java#L68